# How to remove url error?

Tags: php, android, url

I  am trying to develop GCM Push Notification, But i am getting the following error.

> 12-06 12:19:51.780: E/URL(5975): > http://192.168.xxx.108:8085/gcm_server_php/register.php

I am using Wamp server. I keep the gcm_server_php folder in www folder.The IP is my computer IP, and I turn on the server,I also open the port 8085. But still getting the error.

register.php

```
<?php
// response json
$json = array();
/**
* Registering a user device
 * Store reg id in users table
 */
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["regId"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $gcm_regid = $_POST["regId"]; // GCM Registration ID
    // Store user details in db
    include_once './db_functions.php';
    include_once './GCM.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $gcm = new GCM();

    $res = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $gcm_regid);

    $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
    $message = array("product" => "shirt");

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
} else {
    // user details missing
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the error message showing

Comment: 12-06 12:19:51.780: E/URL(5975): > http://192.168.xxx.108:8085/gcm_server_php/register.php     That's the error.

Comment: is it server side error or android ??

Comment: kindly echo helloworld just to confirm server is running

Comment: Actually i am thinking that it is some server side problem because in logcate I am not getting any other error. My device is successfully registered with GCM Server, and I am successfully sending that id to my server. But when I a sendig the Notification, my Android is not getting that Notification.

Comment: Yes Vineet1982 my server is proper running.

Comment: One main thing is that, how can I know that the notification, which I am sending to GCM server, is received by GCM server. I mean i read somewhere that GCM server response to my local server again and send a multicast id, so how can I know that i am receiving that multicast id or not..?

Comment: is your device registered successfully? then not to worry.

Comment: But notification is not coming on my device, problem is that.